# Automatically Deploy Spring Boot Application file changes without manual restart

Tags: spring-boot

Automaticall deploy my spring boot application file changes without manually restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```